# Acro package: use serif font and alignment?

Tags: fonts, acro

I am using `scrbook` and want *serif fonts* for chapter headings etc.

When I am using `acro` package, the acronyms are not printed in serif font similar to the section heads as defined by:

```
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
```

Could someone please help me out here, so that the acronyms are printed in the same serif font and ideally could also tell me, how to *align* the long form of the acronyms to the longest acronym used?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[paper=A4,
               pagesize,
               DIV=calc,
               openany,
               BCOR=8mm,
               numbers=noenddot]
              {scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{acro}

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}                      

\DeclareAcronym{OASIS}{ 
    short = OASIS, 
    long = Organization for the Advancement of Structured Information Standards}

\DeclareAcronym{SOAP}{ 
    short = SOAP, 
    long = Simple Object Access Protocol}

\begin{document}    
\acuseall

\printacronyms[]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just realized how this can be achieved:

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\acsetup{list-style=longtable}
```